# Is there a way to see where Spring Beans are defined?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, spring-bean

I've been having issues with Spring Beans lately. Primarily, I've been getting "No qualifying bean of type 'redacted' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: bean1,bean1butdifferentname"

I tried getting around it with the @Qualifier() annotation, but without success.

Trouble is, the code I'm working on is crazy complex, each class extending, implementing and importing a billion others, so I have no idea where the two beans are defined in the first place.

Is there a way to see where these beans are defined? Through a plugin, maybe?

I'm working in Intellij 2019.2.4

Answer (score 0):

The best generic tool to find code is **grep** from the command line

```
grep BeanName . -r --include \*.java
```

Since you are using IntelliJ you can check all implementations of your interface using **CTRL+LEFT-MOUSE-BUTTON**.

**CTRL+LEFT-MOUSE-BUTTON** on the interface name in your java class definition that implements the interface and it will bring you to the interface

**CTRL+LEFT-MOUSE-BUTTON** on the interface name in the file which defines the interface and it will show you all of the places that use that interface.

If it is a large app it may still take a long time to find because there could be many matches.

On Mac its Command+LEFT-MOUSE-BUTTON